# Phpmyadmin 'Cannot log in to the MySQL server' for root user using phpMyAdmin ready for cloud foundry and bluemix mysql service

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I'm using the My-SQL service on IBM Bluemix, for which I've deployed [phpmyadmin-cf](https://github.com/cloudfoundry-community/phpmyadmin-cf) application to perform db operations. Before deploying I set

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
```

in the config.inc.php

However, when I try to login as root, with credentials:

Username: root

Password: ''

I get the following error: Cannot log in to the MySQL server

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = TRUE;
```

The line above need to be added twice; once within within the if (!empty($dbname)) { statement, and another one outside of it (probably towards the end of the configuration file).

It should be as the following example;

```
if (!empty($dbname)) {
    // other configuration options
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = TRUE;
    // it should be placed before the following line
    $i++;
}

// other configuration options
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = TRUE;
```

Comment: Hey pavlovich, thanks for the reply. I tried your solution and redeployed the application. It still gives me the same error.